# Link To Action Post Method in Laravel

Tags: laravel

How will I pass variable to controller in POST method by link to action.
This is my blade code

```
{{ link_to_action('userviewController@getschoolbranch',$user->userId,['getid' => $user->userNo]) }}
```

These makes the url like http:://localhost/laravel/userview?getid=001
But I want to pass the variable in POST method from blade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do `POST` from `<a></a>` you will have to do an AJAX post.
Here's an example.

HTML
`<a href="#" user-id="001">Get User</a>`
Notice the custom attribute `user-id`.

JAVASCRIPT (Jquery required)

```
$('a[user-id]').click(function(){
 var user = $(this).attr('user-id');
$.ajax({
            url: '/get-user',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {userID: user},
            success: function(data){
                alert(data['success']);
            }
        });
return false;
});
```

ROUTE

```
Route::post('/get-user', 'yourController@getUser');
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function getUser(Request $request){
  //Select from DB where userid = $request->input('userID');

//Return json to the AJAX success function
return response()->json(['success' => 'User found']);
}
```

Hope that help.

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a Form with just a submit button in it. Assuming you are using blade:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('to.post.method', $user->userId) }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="getid" value="{{ $user->userNo }}">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Link Text">
</form>
```

I haven't tested this and it also assumes your routes are set up to handle it but in theory it should work.

Comment: You should add @csrf.